# Difference between Software Architecture document and System Design Document

Tags: architecture

What is the difference between Software Architecture document and System Design Document? Can anyone provide the contents to be captured in SAD??

Answer (score 2):

System usually refers to a product consisting of more than one softwares and/or hardwares.
A System Design Document is written from the point of view of the System.

A Software Architecture Document DOES refer to the Software's connectivity to other modules/the System. But it is written from the point of view of the Software.